# Spark SQL: keep a non-key row after join

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark

I have two dataset as following:

```
smoothieDs.show()

|smoothie_id | smoothie     | price | 
|1           | Tropical     | 10    |
|2           | Green vegie  | 20    |
```

and:

```
ingredientDs.show()

|smoothie     | ingredient    | 
|Tropical     | Mango         | 
|Tropical     | Passion fruit | 
|Green veggie | Cucumber      |
|Green veggie | Kiwi          |
```

I want to join two datasets so that I could get ingredient information for each smoothie whose `price` is lower than 15$, but keep those even if the price is higher, and fill in with a string `To be communicated` for the `ingredient` field.

I tried `smoothieDs.join(ingredientDs).filter(col(price).lt(15))` and it gives:

```
|smoothie_id  |price | smoothie     | ingredient    |
|1            |10    | Tropical     | Mango         | 
|1            |10    | Tropical     | Passion fruit |
```

But my expected result should be:

```
|smoothie_id  |price | smoothie     | ingredient         |
|1            |10    | Tropical     | Mango              | 
|1            |10    | Tropical     | Passion fruit      | 
|2            |20    | Green veggie | To be communicated |
```

Is it possible to achieve this using `join` directly, if not what is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `ingredient` based on the price after the join:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

smoothieDs.join(ingredientDs, "smoothie")
  .withColumn("ingredient", when('price.lt(15), 'ingredient).otherwise("To be communicated"))
  .distinct()
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+-----+------------------+
|    smoothie|smoothie_id|price|        ingredient|
+------------+-----------+-----+------------------+
|Green veggie|          2|   20|To be communicated|
|    Tropical|          1|   10|             Mango|
|    Tropical|          1|   10|     Passion fruit|
+------------+-----------+-----+------------------+
```

**Edit**: another option would be to filter the ingredient dataset first and then do the join. This would avoid using `distinct` but comes at the price of a second join. Depending on the data this can or can not be faster.

```scala
smoothieDs.join(
  ingredientDs.join(smoothieDs.filter('price.lt(15)), Seq("smoothie"), "left_semi"),
  Seq("smoothie"), "left_outer")
  .na.fill("To be communicated", Seq("ingredient"))
  .show()
```

Comment: it will work but in this case the join is unecessarily done